# Cannot make html with Sphinx on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, python-sphinx

I tried to `make html`, but I met some some errors related to Sphinx.

Firstly, I tried

> pip3 install -U sphinx

Version from pip3 list: Sphinx (7.0.1) was installed. However, met an error when `make`

> /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/sphinx-build: not found
> make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Sphinx.dir/build.make:75：output/sphinx/index.html] Error 127

Then I uninstalled the version (7.0.1) installed by pip3 and tried

> sudo apt install python3-sphinx

Version Sphinx (1.8.5) was installed. However, met another error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement CStructObject (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for CStructObject

Environment info

- Linux: Ubuntu 20.04
- Python version: 3.8.10

My understanding so far: The Sphinx version installed through apt is too old to use. The Sphinx version installed through pip3 cannot be found. And this is probably becauce the Sphinx(7.0.1) is installed at `$HOME/.local/bin`. But `$HOME/.local/bin` is not as default in the $PATH. I already tried to add it to path but this does not work.

Very similar to this issue https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/7963. But it does not resolve my problem.